# How to filter json file based on the item of an object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, native

My JSON file's structure is an object with multiple items, which are meals. I need to filter them based on an array `selectedDiseases`.
Here is one of my JSON files, breakfastFood.json:

```
{
  "1": {"name": "Scrambled eggs with asparagus and tomatoes", "stars": 4, "price": "", "disease": "Diabetes", "image_uri":"https://www.sydneymarkets.com.au/recipes/images/asparagus-and-parmesan-scrambled-eggs.jpg", "meal_time": "breakfast"},
  "2": {"name": "Greek yoghurt with mixed berries and chopped almonds", "stars": 3, "price": 0, "disease": "Diabetes", "image_uri":"https://www.almonds.com/sites/default/files/2020-07/abc_BreakfastPairing_A_re01.jpg", "meal_time": "breakfast"},
  "3": {"name": "Oatmeal pancakes with blueberries", "stars": 4, "price": 0, "disease": "Diabetes", "image_uri":"https://s23209.pcdn.co/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/IMG_6988-360x360.jpg", "meal_time": "breakfast"},
  "4": {"name": "Greek yoghurt with mixed nuts, berries, and honey", "stars": 4, "price": 0, "disease": "Diabetes", "image_uri":"https://i0.wp.com/thedomesticdietitian.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/pomegranate-greek-yogurt-bowl-4.jpg?w=870&ssl=1", "meal_time": "breakfast"},
  "5": {"name": "Porridge with shredded chicken", "stars": 5, "price": 0, "disease": "Diabetes", "image_uri":"https://www.theworktop.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/Chicken-Congee-Slow-Cooker.jpg", "meal_time": "breakfast"},
```

This is a small portion from my breakfastFood.json file, you get the idea.

Basically, if in the meal, "disease": "Diabetes" it will show for people who have diabetes, which is stored in a `selectedDiseases` array.

Now if this were an array of objects, I would filter them like this:

```
const filteredBreakfast = foodChoicesForBreakfast.filter((meal) =>
        selectedDiseases.includes(meal.disease)
);
const filteredLunch = foodChoicesForLunch.filter((meal) =>
        selectedDiseases.includes(meal.disease)
);
const filteredDinner = foodChoicesForDinner.filter((meal) =>
        selectedDiseases.includes(meal.disease)
);

// Construct an object containing the filtered food choices
const filteredFoodChoices = {
  breakfast: filteredBreakfast,
  lunch: filteredLunch,
  dinner: filteredDinner,
};
```

How should I do it since my JSON Files are objects of items?

Comment: Perhaps look into using [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need the `key`'s of the filtered objects, you can use `Object.values()` to create an array of objects where you can call `filter()`

```js
const data = {"1": {"name": "Scrambled eggs with asparagus and tomatoes", "stars": 4, "price": "", "disease": "Diabetes", "image_uri":"https://www.sydneymarkets.com.au/recipes/images/asparagus-and-parmesan-scrambled-eggs.jpg", "meal_time": "breakfast"}, "2": {"name": "Greek yoghurt with mixed berries and chopped almonds", "stars": 3, "price": 0, "disease": "Diabetes", "image_uri":"https://www.almonds.com/sites/default/files/2020-07/abc_BreakfastPairing_A_re01.jpg", "meal_time": "breakfast"}, "3": {"name": "Oatmeal pancakes with blueberries", "stars": 4, "price": 0, "disease": "Diabetes", "image_uri":"https://s23209.pcdn.co/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/IMG_6988-360x360.jpg", "meal_time": "breakfast"}, "4": {"name": "Greek yoghurt with mixed nuts, berries, and honey", "stars": 4, "price": 0, "disease": "Diabetes", "image_uri":"https://i0.wp.com/thedomesticdietitian.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/pomegranate-greek-yogurt-bowl-4.jpg?w=870&ssl=1", "meal_time": "breakfast"}, "5": {"name": "Porridge with shredded chicken", "stars": 5, "price": 0, "disease": "Diabetes", "image_uri":"https://www.theworktop.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/Chicken-Congee-Slow-Cooker.jpg", "meal_time": "breakfast"}};
const selectedDiseases = 'Diabetes';

const filtered = Object.values(data).filter(({ disease }) => disease === selectedDiseases);

console.log(filtered)
```